# How to debug simple RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So far, to a very experienced Java EE developer with years of experience in many different languages, I am having real difficulties with Ruby on Rails.  I am using: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15] and Rails 5.0.0.  I am following a very simple on-line tutorial on building a private library web application, BUT, in order to learn something, instead of having Books with a linked table of Subjects, I changed Subjects to Authors since many books have the same authors.  I am using SQLLite for development and MySQL for production( haven't gotten there yet! ).  I find that when you follow exactly the directions in most tutorials, you end up with whatever application you were building.  But, IF you deviate in any fashion, things just don't work and it's very hard to figure out what happened.  You get error messages ( sometimes ) in the logs that you've got an undefined variable or constant.  Normally, you would search for where that variable is used, then be sure you define it or spell it correctly.  However, in RoR, that constant doesn't appear anywhere except in the log, if there.  RoR, due to its conventions, has either created or assumed that you had such a variable, when in fact, you may have named a "view" folder in the singular instead of the plural.  It "invented" a variable to point to that, but it didn't match the pattern, so it fails with very poor error messages.

The server doesn't complain, just does a rollback, and goes on.  The log has some unmeaningful message, as per above.  I end up spending hours trying different patterns for routes suggested by people, or renaming things, but it's all guesswork.

I enjoy working with frameworks and systems where I understand them.  This seems to be a collection of different pieces which parse in yml, yaml, erb, rb, sass, haml, etc.  I've tried logging, but to no avail.  How do you located simple mistakes?

Here is my "books_controller.rb":

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

   def list
     @books = Book.all
   end

   def show
     @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
     @book = Book.new
     @authors = Author.all
   end

   def create
     @book = Book.new(book_params)

     if @book.save
       logger.debug 'Redirecting to list'
       redirect_to :action => 'list'
     else
       @authors = Author.all
       render :action => 'new'
     end

   end

   def edit
     @book = Book.find(params[:id])
     @authors = Author.all
   end

   def update
     @book = Book.find(params[:id])

   if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
   else
      @authors = Author.all
      render :action => 'edit'
   end
   end

   def delete
     Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
     redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end

   def show_authors
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
   end

   def book_params
      params.require(:books).permit(:title, :description, :author_id)
   end
end
```

The new.html.erb under app/views/books is:

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>

<%= form_tag :action => 'create' do %>
<p><label for = "book_title">Title</label>:

<%= text_field 'books', 'title' %></p>

<p><label for = "book_author_id">Author</label>:

<%= collection_select(:book, :author_id, @authors, :id, :name, prompt: true) %></p>
<p><label for = "book_description">Description</label><br/>

<%= text_area 'books', 'description' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>

<% end -%>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

routes.rb is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :books
  #get 'books/list'
  #post 'books/create'
  #get 'books/new'
  #patch 'books/update'
  #get 'books/show'
  #get 'books/edit'
  #get 'books/delete'
  get 'books/show_authors'
  get 'authors/list'
  post 'authors/create'
  get 'authors/new'
  patch 'authors/update'
  get 'authors/show'
  get 'authors/edit'
  root :to => 'books#list'
end
```

When I try to add a new book, I enter the title, select an author, and put in a description and click "Create".  It then just returns to the new screen.  The console has:

```
Started GET "/books/new" for ::1 at 2016-08-04 17:18:22 -0400
Processing by BooksController#new as HTML
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Author Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 21.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started POST "/books" for ::1 at 2016-08-04 17:18:28 -0400
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"noRmEq8rHE6RLs0cPNrlZoQXq//2sr+SAOSHEFc0U3zqbSJZOSKDmdgwpdm5/nVswItHp4Ken0mjggt47ph46Q==", "books"=>{"title"=>"sdfasdf", "description"=>"asdfasdf"}, "book"=>{"author_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Author Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 20.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

and the development log has:

```
Started GET "/books/new" for ::1 at 2016-08-04 17:18:22 -0400
Processing by BooksController#new as HTML
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mAuthor Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"[0m
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 21.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started POST "/books" for ::1 at 2016-08-04 17:18:28 -0400
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"noRmEq8rHE6RLs0cPNrlZoQXq//2sr+SAOSHEFc0U3zqbSJZOSKDmdgwpdm5/nVswItHp4Ken0mjggt47ph46Q==", "books"=>{"title"=>"sdfasdf", "description"=>"asdfasdf"}, "book"=>{"author_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mAuthor Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors"[0m
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 20.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Yes, the transaction was rolled back.  WHY?  How can I get information on what caused the database to "rollback"?  The two tables in the database are:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :author_id
      t.string :description
      t.timestamp :created
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAuthors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :authors do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  validates_presence_of :title
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

I can create a book in rails console as:

```
 b=Book.create :title=>'Test', :author_id=>1, :description=>'Desc'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Author Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("title", "author_id", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Test"], ["author_id", 1], ["description", "Desc"], ["created_at", 2016-08-04 20:17:40 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-04 20:17:40 UTC]]
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Book id: 1, title: "Test", author_id: 1, description: "Desc", created: nil, created_at: "2016-08-04 20:17:40", updated_at: "2016-08-04 20:17:40">
```

I would appreciate input and especially help on understanding why what happened actually happened.  It seems that a very simple error is being made, but I can't see it.

------------------ Added after several answers and "guesses" by me.
I changed the form_tag to a form_for as I'll show below.
----new.html.erb------

```
<%= form_for(@book)  do |f| %>

Title: <%= f.text_field :title %><br/>

Author: <%= select("book", "author_id", Author.all.collect{|p| [p.name,p.id]}, prompt: 'Select') %><br/>

Description: <%= f.text_area :description %><br/>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>

<% end -%>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

I get in the browser:

```
Validation failed: Author must exist, Title can't be blank

Extracted source (around line #18):
16
17
18
19
20
21

   def create
     @book = Book.new
     if @book.save!
       redirect_to :action => 'list'
     else
       @authors = Author.all

Rails.root: /Users/woo/Development/rails/library

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/books_controller.rb:18:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"gi+wVGV3MIlkJsRjO8Ig1cS3YV/OIADSevFJg7ItBesokIiHFDThycTO8/kob+2E1fuPFquFUK+b7bGksWRZGQ==",
 "book"=>{"title"=>"Book", "author_id"=>"2", "description"=>"test"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

As far as I can see, book does have a title, and an author_id, and a description.  Why "Author must exist, Title can't be blank"?

Comment: Ok replace `@book.save` with `@book.save!` and you will see the error right there. This will be your first debugging tool. Let me know what you see, I will help you. :) I assumed you have trouble to create books, no? Please correct me if I am wrong in my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `form_for` instead of `form_tag` in your `books/new` view. This is the Rails way to create forms for model object.

Check a handy guide on form_for [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object).

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error that "undefined method name create for hash"

Comment: Can you edit your question with the new view that use form_for?

Answer (score 0):

> How to debug ....

There are several tools to help debug a Rails application. One you have already discovered: the log file in `log/development.log`.

Another is Byebug. Add the gem to your Gemfile and insert the following in the create action after the 'else':

```
require 'byebug'
byebug
```

then post the form again. The development server will bring up a Byebug console where you can inspect local variables, instance variables, and the stack trace. Try inspecting:

```
@book.errors
```

When an ActiveRecord model fails to save it is usually because validations failed. Errors encountered when saving are added to the `errors` object on the model instance.

The reason for the failure is probably that the form is not passing the expected parameters. By convention, Rails expects attributes for the model to be in a hash where the key is the model name, so `params[:book][:title]`, not `params[:title`]. See the documentation for the `form_for` helper for more info.

Comment: I added a '!' to the @books.save and got:
...Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qvgB2E2d9Wvs7bdkfp9lCKtTazEaJleZO3VAOIXQANHeEUWT25RqvKXz36H7u/UC78+HaW4Kd0KYE8xQPHwrRA==", "books"=>{"title"=>"Book2", "description"=>"A Book"}, "book"=>{"author_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
  
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Author must exist):
  
app/controllers/books_controller.rb:19:in `create'

Comment: It fails due to the validation "Author must exist". The author_id is not set on the book when it is saved. Does the model include `accepts_nested_attributes_for`? See the Rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html, section 9.1.

Comment: No, I'll look into that. The tutorial I was following didn't have that, just what I showed.

Comment: I'd suggest you add a `puts @book` and/or a `byebug` statement immediately before the save, so you can verify the values of the attributes.

Comment: Actually, if `author_id` is just a column in `books`, you shouldn't need `accept_nested_attributes_for`. Sorry, I was anticipating :) But the value is clearly not being set when it should.

Comment: I've updated the post to show the form_for.  Also the error I get.  The dump of book seems to show that title, author_id, and description all have values.

Comment: Try replacing `params.require(:books)` with `params.require(:book)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  With your suggestions and a lot of guessing from ready various Google sites, I combined them and in the new.html.erb put form_for(@book), and then in the create method of books_controller.rb, I put @book - Book.new(book_params), where book_params is:

```
   def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author_id, :description)
   end
```

I'm guessing that this is to handle the strong attribution required by Rails 4 and up.  Before I had books as the first argument and since it existed, but book was not filled, I got the weird error.  After using form_for with @book as an argument, that set the values from the form into the book hash.  Then the params.require with :book as the first argument, looked in that hash to extract title, author_id, and description.

Again, many thanks for the help and I learned about bye bug and save! and so forth.  I find information is very sketchy and ofter the version is not mentioned, thus leading one astray many times.